# Conditional if inside variable

Tags: php, string, variables, if-statement, include

I have `nav.php` and I have 2 variable inside it. I want to include `nav.php` in `index.php` by echoing the variable. The `nav.php` code is as below:

```
<?php 
$TopLeftNav = '<li if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/dashboard.php") echo "class = 'active'" ><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></li>
<li if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/website.php") echo "class = 'active'" ><a href="website.php">Add Website</a></li>
<li php if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/report.php") echo "class = 'active'" ><a href="report.php">Reports</a></li>';

$TopRightNav = '<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>';
?>
```

As you can see, the variable `$TopLeftNav` wont work because the `if` conditional in it. The conditional is for highlighting current active page.

I understand I can make them work by creating separate file for example `nav1.php`, `nav2.php` and separate the navigation html but for learning purposes, how can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the code should just guess when you switch from string literals to PHP code? Why would any of that work?

Comment: *My friend does mad-coding! Just like that!!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do it like this:

```
<?php 
// set the variables we will use to an empty string
$web_class = '';
$dash_class = '';
$report_class = '';

// check the PHP_SELF and set a variable
if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/website.php") {
    $web_class  = 'active';
} elseif ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/dashboard.php") {
    $dash_class  = 'active';
} elseif ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/report.php") {
    $report_class  = 'active';
}

// generate the output
$TopLeftNav = '<li class="'.$dash_class.'"><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></li>';
$TopLeftNav .= '<li class="'.$web_class.'"><a href="website.php">Add Website</a></li>';
$TopLeftNav .= '<li class="'.$report_class.'"><a href="report.php">Reports</a></li>';

$TopRightNav = '<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>';
?>
```

Though I'd be more inclined to do something like this: (a switch statement) http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

```
<?php

// set the variables we will use to an empty string
$web_class = '';
$dash_class = '';
$report_class = '';


switch through the PHP_SELF and set the variables accordingly
switch ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']){
    case '/dashboard.php':
        $dash_class  = 'active';
        break;
    case '/report.php':
        $report_class  = 'active';
        break;
    case '/website.php':
        $web_class  = 'active';
        break;
}

// generate the output
$TopLeftNav = '<li class="'.$dash_class.'"><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></li>';
$TopLeftNav .= '<li class="'.$web_class.'"><a href="website.php">Add Website</a></li>';
$TopLeftNav .= '<li class="'.$report_class.'"><a href="report.php">Reports</a></li>';

$TopRightNav = '<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>';
?>
```

switch statements are great for this kind of thing as the code produced is far more readable when you come back to it in a years time.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Yes, the switch case is easier to understand.

Comment: Love how this answer has suddenly "changed" to something completely different than it was and that now really looks like my answer with the switch statement instead... Oh yeah, and the "change" happened about 10-15 minutes after my answer... makes you wonder.

Comment: changed? is that not the point of this site? can you not edit your own question?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, but not to "borrow" other answers.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

Here im using a tenary operator like this:

`(conditional expression) ? (ouput if true) : (output if false);`

```
<?php 
    $TopLeftNav = '<li  ' . ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/dashboard.php" ? ' class = \'active\' ' : '') . ' ><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li  ' . ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/website.php" ? ' class = \'active\' ' : '') . ' " ><a href="website.php">Add Website</a></li>
    <li ' . ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/report.php" ? ' class = \'active\' ' : '') . ' " ><a href="report.php">Reports</a></li>';

    $TopRightNav = '<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>';
?>
```

Comment: Fix the other lines as well, maybe explain OP what you did. If you want to bring it to another level, use a variable to avoid comparing PHP_SELF the whole time... Plenty of room to optimize this code and show a beginner coder how it's done.

Comment: Rather than just giving him the answer, might be a good idea to explain what you're doing. Anyone who wrote the code in the original question is not going to understand the ternary operator. EDIT: beaten by Shomz!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, since the other answers look more like hacks than something useful to learn from, please consider this approach:

```
<?php 
// three classes for each for easier adding them to the HTML strings
// each of them will be assigned a value of "class = 'active'" in case of matching urls
// or just an empty string otherwise
$dashboardClass = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/dashboard.php" ? "class = 'active'" : "";
$reportClass = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/report.php" ? "class = 'active'" : "";
$websiteClass = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/website.php" ? "class = 'active'" : "";

$TopLeftNav = "
<li $dashboardClass><a href='dashboard.php'>Dashboard</a></li>
<li $websiteClass><a href='website.php'>Add Website</a></li>
<li $reportClass><a href='report.php'>Reports</a></li>";

$TopRightNav = '<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>';
?>
```

So, the idea is to store the value to be echoed for each of the three classes (thus we have three new variables). I've also switched from single quotes to double quotes so that PHP strings are interpolated directly, without having to concat anything, so for example `<li $dashboardClass>` would become `<li class='active'>` in case the PHP_SELF matches dashboard.php, or just `<li>` otherwise.

Ternary operators:

This: `$dashboardClass = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/dashboard.php" ? "class = 'active'" : "";` is the same as this:

```
if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/dashboard.php") {
    $dashboardClass = "class = 'active'";
}
else {
    $dashboardClass = '';
}
```

Comment: I don't see why. This is (ish) how I'd do it (though in reality, of course, templating!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, this is as close as I could get to templating without confusing the OP. :)

Comment: I appreciate your help and the ternary explanation :)

Comment: Please excuse my silliness but why is there 2 double quote at the end of each double dot? Isn't quoting `"class = 'active'"` is enough?

Comment: It's not silliness, everyone was learning that at some point. :) Double dot (or colon) denotes a separator, before it is the "if" case and after it is the "else" case. Like this: `condition ? true_case_here : false_case_here;` Makes sense now?

Comment: So my whole line was like this: `$variable = (condition ? value_if_condition_true : value_if_condition_false);` and the variable gets either first ("class='active'") or the second ("") value, based on the condition.

Comment: So the second got empty string? So that is why viewing source code end up with empty space in `<li >` if it's not active. Brilliant. Sorry I'm a novice in this thing.

Comment: Exactly!! If you wish to get rid of that whitespace, you can do this: `$dashboardClass = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/dashboard.php" ? " class = 'active'" : "";` (note the space before class), and in the HTML: `<li$dashboardClass>` - it will work even though they are glued together now.